# please explain compiler error: Inno Setup: "component cannot be more than one level below the preceding component."

Tags: inno-setup

Could I have a more detailed explanation of this Inno Setup compiler error? "component cannot be more than one level below the preceding component." Perhaps I do not understand what "one level below" means in this context. Perhaps there is a place that I have not found where Inno Setup details its compiler errors. Perhaps I could just be pointed to that place, which I can not find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message is a bit misleading, but it tries to tell you that if you specify a component to be the child of a certain component, you must specify the parent before the child in the `[Components]` section.

For example, this will fail to compile, because the first component's parent `component` is defined later in the section:

```
[Components]
Name: "component\subcomponent"; Description: "Subcomponent"
Name: "component"; Description: "Component"
```

This will fix the problem:

```
[Components]
Name: "component"; Description: "Component"
Name: "component\subcomponent"; Description: "Subcomponent"
```